# WebSocketClient.js:16 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/ws' failed: React, Docker, NGINX

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, websocket, ws

Here's the issue... when I start a React app locally as npm start. I don't have a ws failed connection.

If I start NGINX and React servers within Docker containers I constantly get

> WebSocketClient.js:16 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/ws' failed:

**default.conf**

```
upstream client {
    server client:3000;
}

upstream api {
    server api:5000;
}   

server {
    listen 80;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client;
    }
    
    location /ws {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
    
    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's a video
https://sendvid.com/r41axvub

Answer (score 22):

Add this to .env:

```
WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0
```

See this issue for more explanation and information: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11897

Comment: Thanks for your response. It doesn't appear in a deployment stage once a project is built. So it somehow relates to code changes in a development.

It did the trick!

Comment: I had the same issue when I was trying to fix my deployed app with docker. NGINX setup needed as well but eventually it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. One simple fix is to map the nginx instance to port 3000 on your local machine. Whereever you do post mapping for nginx change it to 3000:80.
Now requests made to 'ws://localhost:3000/ws' by the react app will be appropiately routed.

Answer (score 1):

For custom webpack(v5) config, adding the following settings to webpack.config.js worked for me

```
devServer: {
  client: {
    webSocketURL: 'auto://0.0.0.0:0/ws',
  }
}
```

Nginx configuration part:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend;
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. My react app was being served with/app, i could do this rerouting, then i changed the react app to /route, now it works

Answer (score 0):

You could run https without docker and http with docker.
So you should use wss and ws accordingly.
This was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, at first adding this line to `.env` (as @sarcouilleizi94 mentioned) solved the problem

```
WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0
```

then (in the same project) unexpectedly it stopped working and I had to change it to:

```
WDS_SOCKET_PORT=3000
```

I hope this can help.